# How to get the last commits status in a branch of GitLab projects?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I need to determine the latest commit status of each of my GitLab projects' branches using the GitLab API.

I have referred to [these](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/pipelines.html) [links](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20277) but I could not get the last commit's status details.

Comment: Do you mean you want the absolutely latest _commit_ (be it in any branch) of each project? Or something else?

Comment: @ojrask, at any branch or development branch alone. Anything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gitlab API to do this :

- retrieve all the projects with the [List projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-projects)
- for each project, retrieve all branches with [List repository branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/branches.html#list-repository-branches). The latter request gives the latest commit sha for each branch.
- call [Commit Status API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#get-the-status-of-a-commit) for each of these commits

With bash an [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can do the following :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# edit this if needed
GITLAB_DOMAIN=gitlab.com
GITLAB_PORT=443
GITLAB_BASE_URL=https://$GITLAB_DOMAIN:$GITLAB_PORT
PER_PAGE=1000

# edit this 
PRIVATE_TOKEN=YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN

echo "GET /projects"

projects=$(curl -s  "$GITLAB_BASE_URL/api/v4/projects?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN&page=1&per_page=$PER_PAGE" | \
    jq -r '. | map([.name, .id|tostring ] | join("|")) | join("\n")')

echo "$projects"

while read -r project; do

    IFS='|' read -ra project_t <<< "$project"

    # project name : ${project_t[0]}
    # project id : ${project_t[1]}

    echo "GET /projects/${project_t[1]}/repository/branches for project ${project_t[0]}"

    commits=$(curl -s "$GITLAB_BASE_URL/api/v4/projects/${project_t[1]}/repository/branches?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN&page=1&per_page=$PER_PAGE" | \
        jq -r '. | map([ .name , .commit.id|tostring ] | join("|")) | join("\n")')

    while read -r commit; do

        IFS='|' read -ra commits_t <<< "$commit"

        # branch name : ${commits_t[0]}
        # last commit sha for this branch : ${commits_t[1]}

        echo "GET /projects/${project_t[1]}/repository/commits/${commits_t[1]}/statuses"

        statuses=$(curl -s "$GITLAB_BASE_URL/api/v4/projects/${project_t[1]}/repository/commits/${commits_t[1]}/statuses?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN" | \
            jq -r '. | map([.status, .name] | join("|")) | join("\n")')

        if [ ! -z "$statuses" ]; then
            while read -r status; do

                IFS='|' read -ra status_t <<< "$status"

                # status value : ${status_t[0]}
                # status name : ${status_t[1]}

                echo "[PROJECT ${project_t[0]}] [BRANCH ${commits_t[0]}] [COMMIT ${commits_t[1]}] [STATUS ${status_t[1]}] : ${status_t[0]}"
            done <<< "$statuses"
        else
            echo "[PROJECT ${project_t[0]}] [BRANCH ${commits_t[0]}] [COMMIT ${commits_t[1]}] : no status found"
        fi

    done <<< "$commits"

    echo "------"

done <<< "$projects"
```

Comment: Thanks for the script! Just a minor comment: In my case, I had to query the projects like this: `/users/<my_user_id>/projects` to get also my **private** projects. Otherwise, it would only list the public ones.

Comment: How do I get the ID of a public project?